# How to fetch Marketing cloud DataExtention Metadata using API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, metadata

How can we fetch the properties of a Marketing cloud Data Extention using it's API.
For Example :- there is a Data extention named "ABC" and having feilds(properties) like name(String), age(integer), etc.

I want to fetch the properties of Data Extention with it's data type via API so that I have the information that the DE "ABC" has properties name,age,etc with data type String,integer,etc respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a SOAP Post call leveraging [DataExtensionField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionfield.htm) object.

The SOAPAction should be "Retrieve"

The payload should be something similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                     <RetrieveRequest>
                        <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
                        <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
                        <Properties>Name</Properties>
                        <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
                        <Properties>Scale</Properties>  
                        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                           <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
                           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                           <Value>DE_CUSTOMER_KEY</Value>
                        </Filter>
                     </RetrieveRequest>
                  </RetrieveRequestMsg>  
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can get use more properties on your payload to get more information about your fields, like:

```
<Properties>DefaultValue</Properties>
<Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
<Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
```

More properties to be found in the link to the DataExtensionField documentation provided above.

PS: Don't forget to add `data_extensions_read` scope to your authentication payload, and to your package on Marketing Cloud as well.

For a step by step guide, checkout Gregory's latest article: [Introduction to making API calls to SFMC from POSTman](https://gortonington.com/introduction-to-making-api-calls-to-sfmc-from-postman/)

Comment: Im using the same code but it is giving me error when using by SOAPUI tool:-                                    
 <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in the XML document. ---> Input string was not in a correct format.</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>

Comment: Did you change the {{access_token}} in the payload with your access token?

Comment: yes, I fetched the access token from my MC org using the /V2/token request API

Comment: Did you change the DE_CUSTOMER_KEY as well? I have just tested the payload above and it's working perfectly

Comment: yes I did change the key as per the DE